# React illogical behaviour : deleted all items from a state while using of filter function

Tags: reactjs

I hesitated to make this post but can't figured out why react is setting my useState to empty.

- If I "push" data into the array : it work.
- if I tried to remove an
  targeted element with filter method, all the "js" state is deleted
  even if I don't pass by "setJs" , I just don't know where the problem
  came from.

I made a lot of research, tried many solutions. I'm locked.
Thanks for help and sorry for the english.

here my state :

```
const [js, setJs] = useState([]);
```

my function which add an event listener for the Svg (which is not a component but only a svg file) :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const placesInSvg = document.getElementsByClassName('place');
    for (let i = 0; i < placesInSvg.length; i++) {
      placesInSvg[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        addPlace(event.target);
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

my function which add a seat depending on targeted seat ( I added an event listener which bring seat informations):

```
 const addPlace = (target) => {
let selectedPlace = document.getElementById(target.id);

let placeAjouteeASelection = {
  id: target.id,
  key: `${target.id} ${dateUtilisee} ${heureDebutUtilisee} ${heureFinUtilisee}`,
  nom: target.id.split('Place')[1],
  date: dateUtilisee,
  heureDebutUtilisee: heureDebutUtilisee,
  heureFinUtilisee: heureFinUtilisee,
};

switch (selectedPlace.getAttribute('fill')) {
  case couleurPlaceReservee:
    placeReservee();
    break;
  case couleurPlaceSelectionnee:
    placeSelectionne(selectedPlace.id);
    selectedPlace.setAttribute('fill', couleurPlaceDisponible);
    break;
  case couleurPlaceDisponible:
    placeDisponible(placeAjouteeASelection);
    selectedPlace.setAttribute('fill', couleurPlaceSelectionnee);
    break;
  default:
    selectedPlace.setAttribute('fill', couleurPlaceDisponible);
    break;
}
```

};

and Finally , the code where I don't know what's wrong:

```
  // if the clicked seat booked
  const placeReservee = () => {
    alert('place reservée !');
  };

  // if I click on seat again to remove it from the "js" array state
  const placeSelectionne = (id) => {
//Js state is emptied ! While I do not set it in this use case, and normaly it already has data inside
    let newarray = js.filter(function (element) {
      return element.id !== id;
    });
    console.log('new array', newarray);
    setJs([...newarray]);
  };

  // if I click on free seat I add it into my "js" array state
  const placeDisponible = (newPlace) => {
    setJs((prev) => {
      return [...prev, newPlace];
    });
  };
```

a small animated gif that show the problem :

[image]

**EDIT : SOLUTION FOUND !**

I don't why, but after a lot of effort, test, finaly this code work fine !
Here my solution:

first I set an empty array in addition to my js state :

```
  let j = [];
  const [js, setJs] = useState([]);
```

and the working part, maybe the code can be refactored, but I'm so Happy and proud to have found a working solution :

```
 const addPlace = async (target) => {
let placeAjouteeASelection = {
  id: target.id,
  key: `${target.id} ${dateUtilisee} ${heureDebutUtilisee} ${heureFinUtilisee}`,
  nom: target.id.split('Place')[1],
  date: dateUtilisee,
  heureDebutUtilisee: heureDebutUtilisee,
  heureFinUtilisee: heureFinUtilisee,
};

if (target.getAttribute('fill') === couleurPlaceReservee) {
  alert('place reservée !');
  console.log('j statut', j);
  return;
}

if (target.getAttribute('fill') === couleurPlaceDisponible) {
  j.push(placeAjouteeASelection);
  target.setAttribute('fill', couleurPlaceSelectionnee);
  setJs([...j]);
  return;
}

if (target.getAttribute('fill') === couleurPlaceSelectionnee) {
  j = j.filter((el) => el.id !== target.id);
  target.setAttribute('fill', couleurPlaceDisponible);
  setJs([...j]);
  return;
}
```

};

things I learned from that problem : keep code simple.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if it sounds obvious, but I'd throw some more console.logs in there to discover the answer. Because as it stands, your filter function and state look fine. Check if the value of element.id and id for each cycle of the filter loop are actually equal cause they're probably not. You could change the != to !== to override type differences too.

Comment: Hey Maxwell, I tried to put some console.log and the problem is, the code just didn't go into the filter, in fact, after render the Js state is emptied ! While I do not set it in this use case, and normaly it already has data inside `js.filter((e) => { //"js" state array is empty`